# Simplify long data table into view by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I searching for a solution to create a special view but don't have an idea how to solve it. :(

I try to make it as much clear as I can. 
For better reproducing one time illustrated and as script.

#### data structure:

The database is an Azure Database (I think its SQL Server 2005)
I have following table. (Please don't criticize the structure, it is give and not from me)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeviceData](
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DeviceID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Error] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_e149e28f-5754-4889-be01-65fafeebce16] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [DeviceID] ASC,
 [TimeStamp] ASC
))
```

-

```
DeviceData
-------------------------
ID (identity)  | Int
DeviceID (PK)  | Int
TimeStamp (PK) | DateTime
Error          | String
```

#### sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DeviceData]
       ([DeviceID]
       ,[TimeStamp]
       ,[Error])
 VALUES
       (
         (1, '2013.01.01 10:00:00', "Error 1"),
         (2, '2013.01.01 10:00:00', "Error 1"),
         (3, '2013.01.01 10:00:00', "Error 1"),
         (1, '2013.01.01 10:01:00', "Error 1"),
         (2, '2013.01.01 10:01:00', null),
         (1, '2013.01.01 10:02:00', "Error 2"),
         (3, '2013.01.01 10:30:00', null)
       )
```

-

```
ID | DeviceID  | TimeStamp           | Error
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1         | 2013.01.01 10:00:00 | Error 1
2  | 2         | 2013.01.01 10:00:00 | Error 1
3  | 3         | 2013.01.01 10:00:00 | Error 1
4  | 1         | 2013.01.01 10:01:00 | Error 1
5  | 2         | 2013.01.01 10:01:00 | null
6  | 1         | 2013.01.01 10:02:00 | Error 2
7  | 3         | 2013.01.01 10:30:00 | null
```

#### wanted result

I want now to group the data by device and a "subgroup" over the [Error] field.

I don't know how to descripe it with word, so please look the sample result.

```
DeviceID  | Begin               | End                 | Error
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 2013.01.01 10:00:00 | 2013.01.01 10:02:00 | Error 1
2         | 2013.01.01 10:00:00 | 2013.01.01 10:01:00 | Error 1
1         | 2013.01.01 10:02:00 | 2013.01.01 10:02:00 | Error 2
3         | 2013.01.01 10:00:00 | 2013.01.01 10:30:00 | Error 1
```

It would be very nice if someone can give me a hint how I can solve my view the most effective way.

Regards and thanks from Germany 
Steffen

Comment: I'm having a problem understanding the logic for Begin vs End date here.  Is the end date denoted by the error = null?  I think you need to clarify which record become what in the begin/end

Comment: Hi, a different error value or null is mark the end.

Comment: Maybe there is another by creating a Trigger on [DeviceData] table to build the result I want?

Comment: Only issue is going to be the logic sorrounding the nulls...I posted a semi answer, but it won't be complete until there is logic around which error the 'null' error relates to.

Answer (score 0):

We'll probably have to work through this one as I'm still missing some logic peices here.

```
select deviceid ,min(timestamp) as begin, max(timestamp) as end, error
from devicedata
group by deviceid,error
```

This will return close to the results you want, however it will not group the null error's with the error 1.  That is the 'snafu' that you are facing here...it's how to handle those nulls and relating them to the proper error.  Is it possible that an 8th row exists as:

```
8  | 1         | 2013.01.01 11:30:00 | null
```

If this case can happen, how do you know which record the null relates to?